# How do I import data into a MySQL Model (EER)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, data-modeling, eer-model

I'm new to EER diagrams and visual database modeling.

I have a mySQL model (EER) that I've created that we forward engineer to create our databases with the exported SQL.

When editing a table in the EER, you are able to insert data too. In this case, I have a SQL statement that inserts 250 odd countries into the table.

How can I run this SQL script against my EER - or do I have to type every one in manually?

**Additional Thought:** Perhaps I can specify a Stored Procedure that needs to be run when forward engineering the database?

Comment: RE: Additional Thought - posted this as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384659/how-do-i-automatically-execute-a-mysql-script-or-routine-after-forward-engineeri

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to import from an CSV file as of MySQL Workbench 5.2.45. Mark submitted a feature request and this was the result. :)

Workbench -> Model -> Model Notes -> Inserts -> Import records from an external file.

Comment: My feature request? Cool! What version?